# Is it possible to define parameters through portal for Logic App (Standard)?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a single-tenant logic app and a workflow under it that needs a configurable input. In a multi-tenant logic app, one can define parameters through the azure portal and reference them in workflow definition (actions/ triggers). Is this not possible with a single-tenant logic app?

I am not able to find the answer in the documentation.

I know a deployment template should consult parameters file for this, however, I still have the above question specifically if I am doing stuff through the portal.

**Edit 7/12**

I am referring to the parameters concept explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/parameterize-workflow-app?tabs=azure-portal), and not the parameters tab of the triggers or actions. See below the parameters that we can define through the portal when working with the consumption logic app.

[image]

Comment: @DeepDave-MT all that you have mentioned in your answer is part of MSFT documentation already, and I have read it all long back. What I did not find and need an answer to is, can we define the parameters through the Azure portal interface instead of parameters.json file. This helps if one is not working in VS code or writing JSON templates. This feature is available in consumption logic apps but not standard, see the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: not yet. Support for parameters in the designer (and therefore in the Azure Portal) is on its way, but not available yet.
In VS Code, you can create a parameters.json file.
But in the portal, there's no option (yet) to create/edit parameters.

Bec Lyons (Microsoft) demoed a version of the designer with this in it, although I can't remember if this was in the June Logic Apps Live session, or in the July Integration Down Under session.

In any case, the only currently supported way to do this is to create a parameters.json file and upload it.

You can either do this from VS Code or Azure CLI (using the preview logicapps CLI extension) OR you can FTP to your Logic App and upload it via an FTP client (e.g. FileZilla) - you can get the FTP login details by clicking the "Get Publish Profile" button in the overview of your Logic Apps Standard resource.

Once they release support for this in the Portal/Designer, I'll update this answer.

Also, worth noting that as of this date (July 2021), there are issues using parameters in Managed API Triggers - not sure yet if this is by design, or if it's a bug. Specifically the FileSystem, FTP and FTPWithSSH (SFTP) triggers.

Hope this helps. Probably not the answer you were looking for, though!